# From Lagrangian to equations of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I have a given Lagrangian:

$$L= e^{st}\cdot\frac12\cdot(mv_y^2-ky^2)$$

And are asked to identify the equations of motions, the constants of motions and physical system.

Without the exp-time-term, this wold be a harmonic oscillator with the solution

$$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = -\left(\frac km\right)\cdot y$$ and $$y(t)=\Re\left(Ae^{i\omega t}+Be^{-i\omega t}\right)$$

I'm wondering:

1. How will the $\exp(st)$-term will effect my solution?
2. What will happen to the Lagrangian if I do a transformation of variables $q=\exp(st)\cdot y$?

Comment: The exponential term will change it certainly, the easiest way to see how is actually compute the equations of motion.

Comment: When I compute the equstions of motion I get: exp(s*t)*(y''+s*y'-(k/m)*y)=0. This is a second order linear homogeneous diff. Equation. But when I try to solve this I just get a messy solution that I can't analyse

Comment: Well if you get the equations of motion (might not be worth putting it in as a comment due to limited space and font sizes), then you can compare it to the harmonic oscillator.

Comment: It looks like a solution for the 1D quantum mechanical oscillator rather than the classical oscillator. You should find examples in any introductory QM text.

Comment: Is this a reasonable analyse og my answer:  for little times the harmonic-solution will dominante, but when t--> infinity the exponential-part will take over?

Comment: For your replacement, I would choose $q=e^{st/2}y$.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just write the equations of motion? You will find that you get a second order lienar homogeneous DE with constant coefficients. Such an equation always has a closed form solution in terms of exponentials, so you can solve it; I guarantee the solution is not too bad.  You might even recognize the equation without having to solve it.

---

Edit: OK, more detail.

We have that $L = \frac12 e^{st} (m \dot{y}^2-ky^2)$. The Euler-Lagrange equation of motion is $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{y}} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 0$. When taking the partial derivatives, remember that $y$, $\dot{y}$ and $t$ are independent! When differentiating with respect to $y$, for example, you need to treat $\dot{y}$ and $t$ as constants. This is not the case when doing the total derivative $\frac{d}{dt}$. In that case, you treat everything, including $y$ and $\dot{y}$, as functions of $t$, and apply the chain rule as necessary.

Doing that, we get the following equation:

$$m\ddot{y} + sm\dot{y}+ky=0
$$

This looks similar to the harmonic oscillator but there is a term with $\dot{y}$. Rearranging, we can write this like so:

$$m\ddot{y}= -sm\dot{y}-ky$$

Now we can see that that term represents a force proportional to the velocity and opposite to it; in other words this is a damped oscillator. By doing similar calculations, we can see that the Lagrangian without the exponential term leads to the simple harmonic oscillator equation, as you noticed.

I'm not going to solve the damped oscillator equation in full since you can find the solution in lots of places (for example, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_oscillator#Universal_oscillator_equation)). If you want to solve it yourself, use the usual method: "guess" a solution of the form $y = Ae^{\lambda t}$, plug that into your equation of motion and see what $\lambda$ should be. Depending on the value of $s$, you might need to consider solutions of the form $y = Ate^{\lambda t}$ also.

As for the substitution: if $q = e^{st}y$, then $y = e^{-st}q$ and then it's just a matter of doing the derivatives and sticking that into the Lagrangian. You will not get something very pretty. As has been suggested in the comments, the substitution $q = e^{-st/2}y$ may prove more fruitful.

Comment: Since this does not actually answer either question, this will have better served as a comment.

Comment: @KyleKanos: I didn't directly answer the question because as far as I know that's not the usual policy in this site. This is a homework question, and so rather than giving the answer I'm trying to give hints to the OP so he/she can figure out the answer on their own.

Comment: I've changed my -1 to a +1 because this actually answers the questions without giving the solution away.

Comment: Thank you for tips and tricks! But i still wonder: when I'm using the given transformation i the equations of motion will depend on a exp(-st)-term. What dose it mean that the exp-dependence changes the sign? How does this effect the conserved quantities of the system?